# Ruby mapping array into hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a 2D array with each row like:

`['John', 'M', '34']`

I want to map into an array of Hash with each hash like:

`{:Name=>"John", :Gender=>"M", :Age=>"34"}`

Is there an elegant way of doing that?

Answer (score 7):

```
array_of_rows.map { |n,g,a| { Name: n, Gender: g, Age: a } }
```

or

```
array_of_rows.map { |row| %i{Name Gender Age}.zip(row).to_h }
```

They produce the same result, so pick the one you find clearer. For example, given this input:

```
array_of_rows = [
  ['John', 'M', '34'],
  ['Mark', 'M', '49']
]
```

either expression will yield this output:

```
[{:Name=>"John", :Gender=>"M", :Age=>"34"}, 
 {:Name=>"Mark", :Gender=>"M", :Age=>"49"}]
```

Comment: When I see problems like this I generally ask myself, "What if the data changes in future, the number of keys, for example?". Best to avoid having to change the code, of course, so I prefer #2, but would not hardwire `%i{Name Gender Age}`.

Comment: Sure. Ideally you'd have some metadata associated with the array you could use instead of hard-coding the key names; perhaps it was read from a CSV file, and the first row contains headers that can be repurposed.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using `zip` and then `to_h` (which stands for to hash)

For example:

```
[:Name, :Gender, :Age].zip(['John', 'M', '34']).to_h
=> {:Name=>"John", :Gender=>"M", :Age=>"34"}
```

[Read more about `zip` here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip)

[And read about `to_h` here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

Answer (score 4):

```
people = [['John', 'M', '34']]
keys = %i{Name Gender Age}

hashes = people.map { |person| keys.zip(person).to_h }
# => [{:Name=>"John", :Gender=>"M", :Age=>"34"}]
```

Basically the way I turn combine two arrays into a hash (one with keys, one with values) is to use [Array#zip](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip). This can turn `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` into `[[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]`

This structure can be easily turned into a hash via `to_h`

Answer (score 1):

```
array_of_rows = [
  ['John', 'M', '34'],
  ['Mark', 'M', '49']
]

keys = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age']

[keys].product(array_of_rows).map { |k,v| k.zip(v).to_h }
  #=> [{"Name"=>"John", "Gender"=>"M", "Age"=>"34"},
  #    {"Name"=>"Mark", "Gender"=>"M", "Age"=>"49"}]
```

or

```
keys_cycle = keys.cycle
array_of_rows.map do |values|
  values.each_with_object({}) { |value, h| h[keys_cycle.next]=value }
do
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this

```
array_of_rows = [
  ['John', 'M', '34'],
  ['Mark', 'M', '49']
]

keys = [:Name, :Gender, :Age]

array_of_rows.collect { |a| Hash[ [keys, a].transpose] }
#=>[{:Name=>"John", :Gender=>"M", :Age=>"34"}, {:Name=>"Mark", :Gender=>"M", :Age=>"49"}]
```